# Angularjs reload value in factory

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie in AngularJS and I get some difficulties. I've got an Angular value that should be available globally in some factories. It stores an adressess of other services and by default all values are null:

```
angular.module('env_settings')
.value('address', {

    management: null,
    data_store: null,
    repository: null,

    single_service: null
});
```

The value is filled properly in factory and when I am looking at it in my controllers it has correct values but in rest of my factories it has still null values. I know that I could pass it to factory when I am calling one if its function but is there any way to get the actual state of my value in factories?

Mayabe is there any better way to get value that is available globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem. I am not sure what I was doing wrong but now it works. For everyone who will have similar problem, don't forget to inject your values or constans to factory.